# Angular4 app not running on mobile browsers and IE11

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been trying to run my angular4 app on mobile browser including IE11 and it seems to just show a blank page although the app runs very fine on Chrome browsers.

I've seen many [Answers](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4632) to such situations but it surprisingly doesn't work for me. You could try visiting the [Site](https://noodles-hub.firebaseapp.com).

Comment: The JavaScript is trying to use the object.assign function which is not supported in IE. Is this coming from code you wrote or the Angular framework?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be from the angular framework

Comment: have you included all the required polyfills?

Comment: Thanks man. It's all good now. I un-commented the polyfills already